# Alter DB2 identity to add Cycle Cache and a specific restart value

Tags: sql, caching, db2, identity

I want to alter a db2 identity to cycle cache and to make it (re)start with a specific value, something like:

```
ALTER TABLE  ALTER COLUMN  
    SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (CYCLE CACHE 100) RESTART WITH 32323
```

Is there a way of doing this so that I can add cycle cache as well as make it restart from a specific number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you seeing?  What version and platform of DB2?

The following works on DB2 for IBM i 7.1

```
alter table mytable       
alter column mycolumn     
  set generated always    
  set cycle               
  set cache 100           
  restart with 32323
```

This worked also

```
alter table mytable                
alter column mycolumn              
  set generated always as identity 
  set cycle                        
  set cache 100                    
  restart with 32323
```

Comment: I was using 'set generated always as identity' which was throwing error. This query seems to work fine! Would this query ensure that the column value is generated as identity? Also, how can I restart with the next value (max(id)+1) dynamically depending on the max value inserted in the table (instead of a specific number)? This is because my database already has some data.

Comment: @u009988, I don't think add identity is required assuming the column is already an identity.  But both forms worked for me.  As fars as resetting to MAX+1,   At least on DB2 for i, a subquery is not allowed in the statement.  You'd have to use a stored procedure to retrieve the max value into a variable and then pass the variable into the statement.

Comment: Exactly! you are right @Charles This is what i needed http://www.zinox.com/archives/163 . Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Although the second approach doesnt work on my side. It gives this error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=as identity;set generated always;<space>, DRIVER=3.50.152
 Message: An unexpected token "as identity" was found following "set generated always".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.50.152 . I am using db2 9.x