# Alter column for primary key not working

Tags: sql, db2, alter-table

I created a new table, without auto increment of the primary key and inserted set of predefined data's into the table. Now I need to set the auto increment for the primary key, which I'm not able to set. please suggest the mistake i have done in the query below.

```
ALTER TABLE SYNCBASE.AUTO_LOAD_DATASOURCES
ALTER COLUMN ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 62, INCREMENT BY 1)
```

Till 61 rows i have inserted the records, it has to increment from 62 onwards. but i;m getting error as

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=BIGINT;RCES
ALTER COLUMN ID;SET, DRIVER=3.53.95
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the manual for your DB2 version for correct syntax. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327079/alter-db2-identity-to-add-cycle-cache-and-a-specific-restart-value

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be coming from the fact that you already have data in your database and modifying the primary key would violate the data integrity. Or you may check whether your DBMS allows you to make changes to  a table after creating it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all... we need to drop the identity and then alter the column, only then it works.

```
alter table SYNCBASE.AUTO_LOAD_DATASOURCES alter column ID drop identity;
alter table SYNCBASE.AUTO_LOAD_DATASOURCES alter column ID set generated always as identity (start with 62, INCREMENT BY 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the DDL statement. The column definition doesn't need to be repeated. This statement will work:

```
ALTER TABLE SYNCBASE.AUTO_LOAD_DATASOURCES
    ALTER COLUMN ID SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 62);
```